# Object breaks hierarchy in play mode

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I am trying Unreal, arguably for the first time, I have attached an object to another. It breaks out of hierarchy when I hit play and becomes root object in world outliner. Someone who can enlighten me..?

Answer (score 0):

You can only attach one object to another inside a blueprint. 
If it's a skeletal mesh that you're using you need to assign it to a socket in the settings by creating a socket first in the physics asset or attach it to a bone.